# javaのデータの扱い(Map?)について

Tags: java

javaの初心者です。
以下のようなデータを保持したい場合、どのようにデータを保持し、追加していくのがいいのでしょうか。
追加の際には、「name」と「user」が一つずつ処理され、変数に貯めたいです。
name、userともにString型になります。
nameやuserに関しては可変長です。
nameが重複した際にはすでに存在しているnameのuserとして追加したいです。

※複数のnameに対して、userが所属することもある
※name内でuserは一意になる

```
{
  name_1  : [user_1,user_2,user_4....user_n],
  name_2 : [user_1, user_5....user_n],
  ... : [user_1, user_10, ....user_n ],
  name_n : [user_3, user_5, ....user_n ]
}
```

データの蓄積のイメージ(例)
 1. {}
 2. {name_1 : [user_1]}
 3. {name_1 : [user_1,user_2]}
 4. {name_1 : [user_1,user_2], name_3 : [user_4]}

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 回答しやすいように `name` と `user` のデータ型を **質問を編集して追記** するのがよさそうに思います。また、 `user` のデータ型が `class User {}` のような型だった場合、どのように区別(一意と判断)するのか、も書いた方が良いと思います。(`equals()` メソッドで判断可能、 `userId` が等しいもの 等)

Comment: @harry0000 さん
ご指摘ありがとうございます！

Comment: 「name、userともにString型になります」とのことですが、だとしたら「複数のnameに対して、userが所属することもある」と言うのはどのように表現されるのでしょうか? 私としては一人のユーザを表す`User`クラスといったものを導入した方が、見通しの良いスッキリしたコードになるように思われます。

Comment: @OOPer さん
「nameが複数ある場合に、userが複数のnameに所属することもある」というほうが正です、わかりにくくてすみません。
Userクラスの実装も考えてみます。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 『「nameが複数ある場合に、userが複数のnameに所属することもある」というほうが正です』えーそれは了解しております。表現が悪かったですかね。それをどんなデータ構造で表現するつもりなのか、と言うのを聞きたいのです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` がコレクションの中で一意であることを保証するためには、`Set`を使用するのが良いでしょう。
また、その`Set`が`name`毎に1つ存在することを表すのには`Map`を使用します。

そのため、基本的に`Map<String, Set<String>>`という型を使用することになるでしょう。

一番簡単な方法としては、この型をそのまま使うことです。

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Map<String, SortedSet<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        {
            final SortedSet<String> name1Users = new TreeSet<>();
            name1Users.add("user_1");
            map.put("name_1",  name1Users);
        }

        {
            final SortedSet<String> users = map.get("name_1");
            users.add("user_2");

            map.get("name_1").forEach(System.out::println);
        }

        {
            // "name_3" という key の value がなかった時(value が nullだった時)に、
            // 第二引数で初期値を設定し、その値を返す
            final SortedSet<String> users = map.computeIfAbsent("name_3", k -> new TreeSet<>());
            users.add("user_4");

            map.get("name_3").forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

ただし、この方法だと`Map`や`Set`のメソッドを直接実行することになるため、各処理で何をやっているのかがわかりづらい場合があります。

2つ目の方法は、このコレクション型をラップした(メンバーに持つ)クラスを定義することです。

※このようなクラスを「ファーストクラスコレクション」と呼びます

```
class UserContainer {

    private final Map<String, SortedSet<String>> userMap = new HashMap<>();

    public SortedSet<String> getUsers(String name) {
        return userMap.getOrDefault(name, new TreeSet<>());
    }

    public void addUser(String name, String user) {
        SortedSet<String> users = userMap.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new TreeSet<>());

        users.add(user);
    }

    /**
     * user が所属している name の一覧を返す
     */
    public List<String> getNames(String user) {
        return userMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(user))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

こちらのメリットは

1. メソッド名に意味の分かりやすい名前を付けられる
2. 上記のように`getNames()`のような処理を定義できる
   (毎回このような処理を使う側で書く必要がない)

等が挙げられます。

---

- `user` がソートされるものとして `SortedSet`(`TreeSet`)を使用していますが、ソートされている必要がなければ、`Set`(`HashSet`)を使用してください。
- Java SE 8以降を前提としてstreamを使用していますので、わからない場合は調べたり、質問したりしてください。

Comment: わかりやすい説明ありがとうございます。
回答をもとに実装を試みてみます。